# Sort array by month and year

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I need help with sorting an array by month and year to display on chart respectively.

```
Array1: ['Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19'....];
Desired Output : [....'Apr18','May18','Jun18','Jul18','Jan19','Mar19'];
```

I also have another array with values for each month according to the array above respectively

```
Array2: ['Mar19_value','Apr18_value','Jun18_value','Jul18_value','May18_value'
       ,'Jan19_value'....];

Array2: ['55','2','3','0','21','132'....]; //real values
```

When the `monthyear` array sorts, I want the data in this array to move to a new position according to the `monthyear` position. Like this:

```
Desired Array1: [....'Apr18','May18','Jun18','Jul18','Jan19','Mar19'];
Desired Array2: [....'Apr18_value','May18_value','Jun18_value','Jul18_value','Jan19_value','Mar19_value'];
```

So I can pick the data later like this:

```
var label = array[4];
var value = array2[4];
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could get the date as a sortable string and sort it.

For getting more than one array sorted by one signature array, you could take sorting with map, where you sort an array of indices, indicating the final sorting and then reassign all arrays with this sorting.

The `getD` function returns a formatted string by taking an index of `array0` for sorting. Inside of the function the string is destructed into month and year parts, and replaced by its [**ISO 8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) representation. The replacement function callback takes the matched items, returns an array with a formatted year and the month of an object with the month names and the related month numbers. Then, this array is joined and returned.

Sorting takes place with a comparison with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
var array1 = ['Mar19', 'Apr18', 'Jun18', 'Jul18', 'May18', 'Jan19'],
    array2 = ['Mar19_value', 'Apr18_value', 'Jun18_value', 'Jul18_value', 'May18_value', 'Jan19_value'],
    array3 = ['55', '2', '3', '0', '21', '132'],
    indices = Object
        .keys(array1)
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            function getD(i) {
                var months = { Jan: '01', Feb: '02', Mar: '03', Apr: '04', May: '05', Jun: '06', Jul: '07', Aug: '08', Sep: '09', Oct: '10', Nov: '11', Dec: '12' },
                    s = array1[i];
                return s.replace(/^(...)(.+)$/, (_, m, y) => [y.padStart(4, '0'), months[m]].join('-'));
            }
            return getD(a).localeCompare(getD(b));
        }),
    result = [array1, array3].map(a => indices.map(i => a[i]));
  
result.forEach(a => console.log(...a));
```

Comment: Are you sure the sorting is correct format? i think you are sorted `MMDD` Format its a `MMYY`

Comment: @prasanth, thank you for the hint. i thought, the number is a day.

Comment: if i only want to perform this with array 1 and array 3?

Comment: @AmirQureshi, then you need oly the wanted array in the array for getting a new sort. please see edit.

Comment: do you want to get new arrays?

Comment: yes but i figured it out , i could not remember how to, but now i do. i really appreciate the help . it is giving me the desired output. Do you mind telling me what is actually happening in function getD() so i can learn to use, such as .padStart , .localeCompare.?

Answer (score 14):

You need change the string to [`new Date(dateString)` format](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) like

```
new Date(Month Date Year)
```

**Updated regex Pattern for Both Array**

https://regex101.com/r/h1cm1z/2/

**Updated** Sort Second array based on first array sorting index

```js
var arr1 =  ['Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19'];
var arr2 =['55','2','3','0','21','132'];

function datesort(arr){
 return arr.concat().sort((a,b)=>{
 a = a.replace(/(\d+)(.*)/g,' 1 $1'); // Month 1 YEAR
 b = b.replace(/(\d+)(.*)/g,' 1 $1'); // Month 1 YEAR
  return new Date(a) - new Date(b)
})
}

var after_arr1 =new datesort(arr1);
var after_arr2 = arr1.reduce(function(a,b,c){
     var ind = after_arr1.indexOf(b);
     a[ind] = arr2[c]
     return a
},[]);


console.log(after_arr1.join(','));
console.log(after_arr2.join(','))
```

Comment: Thank you , it works as required. What if i have another array with values for each month respectively according to the monthyear array. how do i sort it when the monthyear moves to a new position. do you understand what i am saying?

Comment: i could added the format of date .you could change your array value like this.If you have any new position .Kindly change regex pattern and reproduce the same date format.Or post your new position. i will give the matching pattern

Comment: Or where did you get this array? You could format array with in pattern on the place of array create.or  with something added delimiters like `MM_YY,YY-MM`

Comment: I think you did'nt understand the updated question mate. the answer you gave to sort the array is working and its fine. but when i sort array1 i also need array2 sorted accordingly to array1 so i can fetch the info from arrays as show above

Comment: you need to sort array2 based on array1 sorted index position right?

Comment: yes , so the month and their values get at same index in both arrays.

Comment: array2 all are 0. You can't see any change in result

Comment: can you put numbers instead of strings in array2 in your answer. it does not seems to be working with me.

Comment: @AmirQureshi I was updated array2 as number. Check my answer is working good as you desired result.see console

Comment: Please do not use date constructor like this. This date format is non standard, it might work but no guarantee.

Answer (score 9):

```js
const input = ['Mar19', 'Apr18', 'Jun18', 'Jul18', 'May18', 'Jan19'];

//const output : ['Apr18','May18','Jun18','Jul18','Jan19','Mar19'];
//Can be done easily by using momentjs, darte-fns, but here i will do it natively

const t = {
  Jan: 1,
  Feb: 2,
  Mar: 3,
  Apr: 4,
  May: 5,
  Jun: 6,
  Jul: 7,
  Aug: 8,
  Sep: 9,
  Oct: 10,
  Nov: 11,
  Dec: 12
}
const giveConcatString = (a, t) => {
  const monthPart = a.substr(0, 3)
  const yearPart = a.substr(3)
  return `${yearPart}${t[monthPart]}`
}
const sortedArray = input.sort((a, b) => {
  const concatString = giveConcatString(a, t)
  const concatStringB = giveConcatString(b, t)
  return concatString <= concatStringB ? -1 : 1

})
console.log(sortedArray)
```

This may help you solve this problem. Did it natively.

Answer (score 9):

To order properly you need to know the order of the months. This is not alphabetical so you can use an array with the order of the months then look them up.

const monthOrder = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

Is already properly sorted and can be used in conjunction with .indexOf() to get the position of a month.

```js
const myArr =  ['Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19'];
const myArr2 = ['Mar19_value','Apr18_value','Jun18_value','Jul18_value','May18_value'
   ,'Jan19_value'];

const monthOrder = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

let sortYearMonth = (a, b) => {
    let monthA = monthOrder.indexOf(a.slice(0,3))
 let yearA = a.slice(3,6)
 let monthB = monthOrder.indexOf(b.slice(0,3))
 let yearB = b.slice(3,6)
 return (`${yearA}-${monthA}` < `${yearB}-${monthB}`) ? -1 : (`${yearA}-${monthA}` > `${yearB}-${monthB}`) ? 1 : 0
}

let sortedMonths = myArr.sort(sortYearMonth)
let sortedMonths2 = myArr2.sort(sortYearMonth)

console.log(sortedMonths )
console.log(sortedMonths2 )
```

**Update: values in same position**

Updated version links the two arrays together then sorts the first while keeping the relative position to the second.

Idea: Link two arrays with a temporary Object then extract the key/value pair using `Object.entries`. Then sorting the array based on the first value of the pair, which is the value of array1. Then it returns the key/value pair in the right order you can extract the values into two arrays again by using `.map()`

I added a run with the string based example and the real values examples below

```js
const myArr = ['Mar19', 'Apr18', 'Jun18', 'Jul18', 'May18', 'Jan19'];
const myArr2 = ['Mar19_value', 'Apr18_value', 'Jun18_value', 'Jul18_value', 'May18_value', 'Jan19_value'];

const myArr3 = ['55','2','3','0','21','132'];

const monthOrder = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

let sortYearMonth = (a, b) => {
  let monthA = monthOrder.indexOf(a.slice(0, 3))
  let yearA = a.slice(3, 6)
  let monthB = monthOrder.indexOf(b.slice(0, 3))
  let yearB = b.slice(3, 6)
  return (`${yearA}-${monthA}` < `${yearB}-${monthB}`) ? -1 : (`${yearA}-${monthA}` > `${yearB}-${monthB}`) ? 1 : 0
}

function sortByFirst(myArr, myArr2) {
  let keyValue = myArr.reduce((links, item, i) => {
    links[item] = myArr2[i];
    return links
  }, {})
  let entries = Object.entries(keyValue)
  return entries.sort((a, b) => sortYearMonth(a[0], b[0]))
}

let sortedEntries = sortByFirst(myArr, myArr2)
let sortedMonths = sortedEntries.map(i => i[0])
let sortedValues = sortedEntries.map(i => i[1])

let sortedEntries2 = sortByFirst(myArr, myArr3)
let sortedMonths2 = sortedEntries2.map(i => i[0])
let sortedValues2 = sortedEntries2.map(i => i[1])

console.log(sortedMonths)
console.log(sortedValues)

console.log(sortedMonths2)
console.log(sortedValues2)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this raw snippet.

```js
var MY = ['Mar19', 'Apr18', 'Jun18', 'Jul18', 'May18', 'Jan19'];
var s = "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec";
// converting to raw date format
for (i in MY) {
  num = MY[i].match(/\d+/g);
  letr = MY[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
  MY[i] = (s.indexOf(letr) / 3 + 1) + '-' + '20' + num;
}
// sorting logic
var sorted = MY.sort(function(a, b) {
  a = a.split("-");
  b = b.split("-")
  return new Date(a[1], a[0], 1) - new Date(b[1], b[0], 1)
});
// converting back to original array after sorting
res = [];
for (i in sorted) {
  var a = sorted[i].split('-');
  res[i] = (s.substr((parseInt(a[0]) - 1) * 3, 3)) + '-' + a[1].substr(2, 2);
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

I used lodash for sorting and `substring` method to divide date into month and day parts

```js
const data = ['Mar20','Mar21', 'Mar01', 'Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19']

const monthMap = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

const sorted = _.sortBy(data, date => monthMap.indexOf(date.substring(0,3)), date => date.substring(3,5))

console.log(sorted)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let mth = ['Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19'];

mth.sort((itemA, itemB)=>{
   let mthAstr = itemA.slice(0,3)+" 01 "+itemA.slice(3,5);
   let mthA = new Date(mthAstr);
   let mthBstr = itemB.slice(0,3)+" 01 "+itemB.slice(3,5);
   let mthB = new Date(mthBstr);
   if (mthA < mthB)
      return -1;
   if (mthA > mthB)
      return 1;
   return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
var Array =  ['Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19'];
Array.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = [a.slice(0,3), ' 20', a.slice(3)].join('');
    b = [b.slice(0,3), ' 20', b.slice(3)].join('')
    return new Date() - new Date(b);
});
            
console.log(Array);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that your data structure is unfortunate.  Working with shared indices makes it much more difficult than a data structure that combines them, such as an array of objects, `[{label: 'Mar19', value: 55}, ...]`.

If your data is coming from an upstream solution you cannot control, you can still manage this in your own work, converting before you use it.  (And if you really have to converting back to pass to others.)

A common name for a function combining two arrays is `zip` -- think of it acting like a zipper.  This version uses one that takes a function to say how the paired elements should be combined.  (Elsewhere such a function might be called [`zipWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith).)

Here `sortArraysByDate` calls `zip` passing a function that turns `'Mar19'` and `55` into `{label: 'Mar19, value: 55, month: 'Mar', year: 19}` using `dateFields` to extract the month and year from that label, then sorts these using the straightforward  `dateSort`

```js
const months = {Jan: 1, Feb: 2, Mar: 3, Apr: 4,  May: 5,  Jun: 6,
                Jul: 7, Aug: 8, Sep: 9, Oct: 10, Nov: 11, Dec: 12}
                
const dateFields = (d) => ({
  month: d.slice(0, 3),
  year: Number(d.slice(3))
})

const dateSort = ({month: m1, year: y1}, {month: m2, year: y2}) =>
  (y1 - y2) || (months[m1] - months[m2])

const zip = (fn, a1, a2) => a1.map((a, i) => fn(a, a2[i]))

const sortArraysByDate = (a1, a2) =>
  zip((label, value) => ({label, value, ...dateFields(label)}), a1, a2)
    .sort(dateSort)
    .map(({label, value}) => ({label, value}))


const Array1 = ['Mar19','Apr18','Jun18','Jul18','May18','Jan19'];
const Array2 =   ['55','2','3','0','21','132']; //real values

const result = sortArraysByDate(Array1, Array2)

console.log(result)
```

The `map` call in `sortArraysByDate` is quite possibly not necessary.  Without it, the resulting data includes extra `year` and `month` fields; that might not be an issue.

If you really need those updated arrays in the original format, you can just `map` the result:

```
const newArray1 = result.map(o => o.label)
const newArray2 = result.map(o => o.value)
```

But I would urge you not to do this unless it's absolutely necessary.  This structure is really useful.  The paired arrays are much less so.

Also, if you need to combine more than two arrays, you could write a slightly more sophisticated version of `zip`:

```
const zip = (fn, ...as) => as[0].map((_, i) => fn(...as.map(a => a[i])))
```

This takes a function on `n` arguments, and `n` arrays, and yields a new array containing the result of calling that function respectively on the successive items in each of the arrays.